# Querystring Encryption & Manual User Input

Tags: encryption, query-string

I'm using the rijndael algorithm for querystring encryption. 

A link is as follows;

www.website.com/webpage.aspx?A=1&B=1

Encrypted;

www.website.com/webpage.aspx?enc=andomcharacters

In this case it works fine, but if the user manually enters the first link to the URL bar, the page will still show with accurate data. 

How can I tell if the user guessed & entered this querystring? I need to block them to do so, since its a security breach.

Answer (score 0):

Check that a variable called enc is always present, and that it is correct.
And maybe check that that is the only variable present

Comment: The thing is when you select an ID from grid, it encrypts/decrypts it first by checking if query.StartsWith("enc").

Comment: Doesn't that mean if query.startswith() returns false, that's a security breach?

Comment: Nope, because when you select an ID from the grid the page postbacks with the selected ID before encrypting it.

Comment: I've decided to use session to solve my problem, it's not the best solution tho, thank you.